# Bulk updating DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a efficient way to update many item on dynamoDB table? I am making on by one update, bu I am consuming all the write capcity. How can I put a limit on used write capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Because `BatchWriteItem` does **not** support item updates, you could not use this API to update multiple items in a single API call.

**Purchasing Reserved Capacity**

You best option (now) to optimize cost (write throughput) is considering [purchasing reserved capacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.ReservedCapacity).

Reserved capacity pricing works better than on-demand pricing. Effectively you could work around your problem by being able to provision more write throughput capacity to the table for the same cost as you would with on-demand pricing.